# Getting file-size property from Nautilus

Tags: c, linux, nautilus

I am hacking on Evince and trying to add a feature that shows the size of the file in the file-property page.

But I am unable to get the file-size value from Nautilus file info.

Does anybody how to get size-info of a file from Nautilus? 
I can get it in terminal using **ls -l** and **stat** commands.

Comment: If you *can* get a fully specified file name, then you can use [`stat`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/stat.html) in your own code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming Evince uses [GIO](https://developer.gnome.org/gio/stable/) (I failed to find a way to quickly browse its code), you can use e.g. [`g_file_query_info()`](https://developer.gnome.org/gio/stable/GFile.html#g-file-query-info) to get a `GFileInfo`  pointer.

You can then use [`g_file_info_get_size()`](https://developer.gnome.org/gio/stable/GFileInfo.html#g-file-info-get-size) to get the size of the file.